# Application Intermittently goes to Not responding

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, memory

We have an application built in *`.Net 4.5(C#, Winforms)`* which only in one production environment goes to `NOt Responding`state intermittently for `10 to 20 second.`

I have written log on important lines. It hangs on loading heavy user controls and when data fetching calls are done.

The system on which it hangs has considerably low memory 2GB. I have almost reproduced the situation on a local machine by lowering the memory. My question is what are my options to avoid these hangs up.
The application memory does raises `200 to 300 mb.`

The behavior is not consistant. Some time it takes 30 seconds to complete a task the next time it takes 3 seconds hardly. 
The Not responding state comes usually in the start up.

My last attempt was i loaded the important assemblies on start up but i have no luck.

Lastly let me tell you that we have several third party controls.

Comment: To prevent application freeze, you need at least to thing. First you need to run heavy task asynchronously. Use thread or task or async methods. Second, do not load all data in the view. Use paging/filtering.

Comment: @Kalten, the calls are async. Yes the second option is also some which is taken care of.. Currently i am relating it memory.. do you think i am the right direction.. The application is in live enviroment for more than 5 years,

Comment: Can you post some code where you do the loading?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concern about memory allocation,

Use the .NET Memory Allocation option of the Performance Wizard found in the Analyze menu to create a Performance Session which will help you figure out what changes you need to make in your code to reduce memory usage.

We really need more info here. But a few suggestions:

> Use the using keyword or call Dispose() on all disposable objects when
>   you are done with them
>
> Make sure you unregister event handlers when you are done listening
>   for events

If you have lot of timers in your application,

This is only a problem with the System.Threading.Timer class if you don't otherwise store a reference to it somewhere. It has several constructor overloads, the ones that take the state object are important. The CLR pays attention to that state object. As long as it is referenced somewhere, the CLR keeps the timer in its timer queue and the timer object won't get garbage collected. Most programmers will not use that state object, the MSDN article certainly doesn't explain its role.

System.Timers.Timer is a wrapper for the System.Threading.Timer class, making it easier to use. In particular, it will use that state object and keep a reference to it as long as the timer is enabled.

Comment: the Disposing and unregistering events is done.. Let me share you one more thing we have lots of timer,

Comment: So the answer to your question appears to be that the timer is not eligible for Garbage collection and will not be collected if you don't maintain a reference to it.

Comment: Use System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer, you'll find that the timer is garbage collected and you can reduce memory consumption with it.